# Display Template Date Format not working to display mm/dd/yy Please Help!

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, display-template

I have a display template that is working, however it is not displaying the date in the format that I want.

I need it in the following format **MM/DD/YY** I had someone trying to help but they bailed on me.

**I need to get this resolved as soon as possible.**

I have tried a variety of methods and none are working I would really appreciate any help.  I have attached the code and an image of the date displayed in the incorrect format.

```
    <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>List Table Item-Countermeasures-v2</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">ListID','ListItemID','ContentTypeId','Link URL':'Path','Property 1':'Title','Property 2':'','Property 3':'','Property 4:'','Property 5':'','Property 6':'StartDate','Property 7':'','Property 8':'','Property 9':'','Property 10':'','FileExtension','SecondaryFileExtension'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">This is the item row template, use this template in combination with the List Table Control template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://share.philips.com/sites/STS020170908232517/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_List_Item-CM-v2.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="TwoLines">
<!--#_
// Give up your names for the properties in the following array
var propertyNames = {"Property 1":"Segment","Property 2":"Region","Property 3":"Description","Property 4":"Assigned To","Property 5":"Start Date","Property 6":"Due Date","Property 7":"Issue Status","Property 8":"Countermeasure-Smart","Property 9":"Gap $","Property 10":"Amount Gap Closed","Property 11":"","Property 12":"","Property 13":""};

var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_tableitems_");

var linkURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Link URL");
linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
var iconURL = Srch.ContentBySearch.getIconSourceFromItem(ctx.CurrentItem);

var listID = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ListID');
var listItemID = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ListItemID');
var ContentTypeId = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ContentTypeId');



var startDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "Start Date"));

var rowId = encodedId + "row";
var editCellId = rowId + "_cell";

var currentItemIdx = ctx.CurrentItemIdx + 1;
var alternating = currentItemIdx % 2 === 0 ? "ms-alternating" : "";

if (currentItemIdx === 1) {
_#-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!--#_ 
            // Show the file icon
            _#-->

            <!--#_ 

            // Show the properties that aren't empty
            for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
                var property = $getItemValue(ctx, String.format("Property {0}", i));
                if(property.managedPropertyName !== String.format("Property {0}", i)) {
                    var propertyName = typeof propertyNames[property.propertyLookupName] === "undefined" ? property.managedPropertyName : propertyNames[property.propertyLookupName];
            _#-->
            <th class="ms-vh2">
                _#= propertyName =#_ 

                <span id="_#= property.managedPropertyName.replace(/ /g, '-') =#_">
                    <span style="" class="sortarrow ms-sortarrowup-iconouter" ></span>
                    <a id="_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_ASC" href="#" title="Ascending" onclick="$getClientControl(this).sortOrRank('_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_ASC');return false;">
                        <img alt="Ascending" src="/_layouts/15/images/sortaz.gif">
                    </a>
                    <a id="_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_DES" href="#" title="Descending" onclick="$getClientControl(this).sortOrRank('_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_DES');return false;">
                        <img alt="Descending" src="/_layouts/15/images/sortza.gif">
                    </a>
                </span>
            </th>
            <!--#_ 
                }
            } 
            _#-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<!--#_
}
_#-->
       <tr id="_#= rowId =#_" class="_#= alternating =#_ ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover">
            <!--#_
            // Show the properties that aren't empty
            for(var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) { 
                var property = $getItemValue(ctx, String.format("Property {0}", i));
                if (property.managedPropertyName !== String.format("Property {0}", i)) {
            _#-->
                <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">

            <!--#_
                    if(!property.isEmpty)
                    {
                        var value = i === 1 ? String.format("<a href='{0}' class='ms-listlink'>{1}</a>", linkURL, property) : property; 
                    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(property.value) === '[object Date]') {value = startDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
            _#-->


                    _#= value =#_
            <!--#_
                        if (i === 1 && !listID.isEmpty && !listItemID.isEmpty && !ContentTypeId.isEmpty) {
                            var viewPropUrl = String.format('/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?ListId={0}&ID={1}&ContentTypeID={2}&Source={3}', listID, listItemID, ContentTypeId, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
            _#-->
                            <span title="Open Menu" class="NotificationDiv ms-ellipsis-a" rel="_#= viewPropUrl =#_" ref="_#= property =#_" path="_#= linkURL =#_" style="cursor: pointer; margin-top: 3px; float: right;">
                                <img alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png" class="ms-ellipsis-icon">
                            </span>
            <!--#_
                        }
                    }
            _#-->
                </td>
            <!--#_
                }
            } 
            _#-->
        </tr>
<!--#_
if (currentItemIdx === ctx.CurrentGroup.RowCount) {
_#-->
    </tbody>
<!--#_
}
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Thank you for your help*
Dorinda[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for something like this:

```
var revisiondate = $getItemValue(ctx, "PAIntraActiveRevisionDate");
        var ContentExpired = false; 
        if(!$isEmptyString(revisiondate.inputValue))
        {
            var thisdate = new Date();
            var parseRevDate = new Date(revisiondate);
            revisiondate = parseRevDate.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
            if(parseRevDate < thisdate)
            {
                ContentExpired = true;
            }
        }
```

//HTML section

```
       if(ContentExpired == true)
                {
                _#-->
                <td id="revisiondateexpired-_#= ListItemIdentifier =#_" class="cpo_RevisionDateExpired" style="padding:10px;"> _#= revisiondate =#_ </td>
                <!--#_
                }else {

                _#-->
                <td id="revisiondateexpired-_#= ListItemIdentifier =#_" style="padding: 10px" class="cpo_RevisionDate"> _#= revisiondate =#_ </td>
                <!--#_
                }
                _#-->
```

Comment: I have tried several versions of this and it never works i still get the full thing I will try again with the refinablestring to see if it works

Comment: I must be doing something wrong I cant seem to get this working

Comment: You are using the revision variable in the HTML section right? In the dev tool (F12) in Chrome you can set a breakpoint in the item display template and inspect the values of the variables

Comment: Does the date need to be the RefinableInt??? i have it as a date and i have one as a string?  does it make a difference?

Comment: No, a string will do too as long as it matches the date format. "March 5th 2019" will not do but 04/03/2019 will

Comment: ok so this is what is on line 37 and 38 Var revisiondate = $getItenValue(ctx, "RefinableString168");
Var parseRevisiondate = new date(revisiondate);  down in the html is where i am not sure what is supposed to go there

Comment: this is what i am showing in the html  <!--#_
                    if(!property.isEmpty)
                    {
                        var value = i === 1 ? String.format("<a href='{0}' class='ms-listlink'>{1}</a>", linkURL, property) : property; 
     if (Object.prototype.toString.call(property.value) === '[object Date]') {value = parseRevisiondate.format('dd/MM/yy');
}      
            _#-->

Comment: I think i am missing a step here please help.

Comment: I have updated the answer